# Filtering a Dataframe by iterating through values from another spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to spark with a specific question, which I tried to solve and search for, for hours and still stucking.

I have two Dataframes. A big one (A) with Columns:
{"ANames", "description", "id", and more}

Another one (B) with only one column "BName". Since that, I know I should convert it into an other type, but I'm not sure in what (list, sequence..). That would be my first question.

At the end I want to search for (filter) each name "BName" in B through "ANames". And afterwords if it found a one of the names, write it in another Dataframe with the structure:

{Bname, id}

It sound complicated. But actually it only should look up some words in a Dataframe.

Edit: "ANames" could contain more than one name (ex. [John Senna, Bred Ford]), "BName" not. And later I also want to search for each "BName" also in "description".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join two dataframes with "array_contains" function:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._

val aData = List((Array("John Senna", "Bred Ford"), "Any description", 11), (Array("NoName"), "No description", 12))
val bData = List("Bred Ford")

val aDF = sparkContext.parallelize(aData).toDF("ANames", "description", "id")
val bDF = sparkContext.parallelize(bData).toDF("BName")

val result = bDF.join(aDF, expr("array_contains(ANames, BName)"), "inner").select(col("BName"), col("id"))
result.show(false)
```

output:

```
+---------+---+
|BName    |id |
+---------+---+
|Bred Ford|11 |
+---------+---+
```

Similar approach can be used later for search in description.

Comment: The expr("array_contains(ANames, BName)") didn't work for me. I guess the quotes should be inside: array_contains("ANames", "BName")
But even this didn't work, so I tried around nearly each possibility. Often there was a curious thing: for the first column, if I surrounded it with "aDF()", it wanted a String rather than a column and if I removed it again, it wanted a column rather than a string.

Comment: On the end it worked as I deleted the "expr(array_contains())" and just putting contains between the two columns. 
At least it's still running without a error since 20min :-D

Comment: can you please try all this example, for start, without modifications?
It worked fine on my env.

Comment: Strange, yes, if I take exactly the same, it's working. So thanks a lot.